# Can I use a UK leave to remain card to enter and exit the UK?

Tags: uk, paperwork

I had a visitor visa and I applied for an extension and my application was approved. They issued me a Biometric Residence Permit "Visit Leave to Remain."

With this card, can I leave and re-enter the UK?

Comment: Did they issue you with a card? What type of permit did they issue you with? On the card it should be under Type of Permit?

Comment: @RodneyHawkins the answers to your questions appear to be present in the question, though the word "visit" was deleted by Dorothy; I have restored it.  The answers are "yes" (the BRP is a card, and it is mentioned in the question "with this card can I leave...") and "visit leave to remain."

Comment: @Dorothy if you search for images of leave-to-remain BRP cards, you'll see that they invariably list the category before noting "leave to remain"; I have therefore restored the word "visit" to the question.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do - do you want to travel without your passport?